# XPath: exclude child element

Tags: xpath

I scrape content using XPath. What i have to scrape is a content in a `div` with given `id`. Inside of this `div` there is another `div`, which content i don't want to scrape.

I use following XPath:

`//[@id='Main'][not(contains(div/@id, 'orderform'))]`

But with this XPath i get extraction not from all urls, like i expect, but from those urls, which do have `div id="Main"` and don't have `div id="orderform"` inside it.

What XPath should i use instead to scrape the whole `div id="Main"`, but excluding the content of `div id="orderform"`?

Comment: post the html code

Comment: @宏杰李 edited post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//*[@id='Main']//*[not(div[@id="orderform"])]
```

the `div` tag is a child tag, you should go down a level.

```
//*[@id='Main']/*[not(div[@id="orderform"])]
```

Comment: it works, but it extracts each html element as certain entity, so i get instead of one extracted column 316 columns :) is it possible to get everything into the same?

Comment: @Chilly Bang you must access the child tag then filter it, I update the answer, it's the best i can do

Comment: there are 16 columns now:)